# Send UDP message every X second in Java

Tags: java, udp

I'm trying to send a message every X second with UDP protocol, but with this code, only one message is sending, and no error appear. Can you help me ?

This is my main where there is a loop and a sleep for 1 second :

```
    Thread t = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    UDPSender sender = new UDPSender(1000, "localhost");
                    sender.send("message");
                    sender.close();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();
```

And here is my class UDPSender which manage UDP and permit to send the message (this works but I put it FYI) :

```
public class UDPSender {

private DatagramSocket socket;
private InetAddress address;
private int port;

private byte[] buf;

public UDPSender(int port, String address) {
    this.port = port;

    try {
        this.socket = new DatagramSocket();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        this.address = InetAddress.getByName(address);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String send(String msg) {
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " - sent: " + msg);

    this.buf = msg.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket packet 
      = new DatagramPacket(this.buf, this.buf.length, this.address, this.port);
    try {
        this.socket.send(packet);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    packet = new DatagramPacket(this.buf, this.buf.length);
    try {
        this.socket.receive(packet);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
}

public void close() {
    this.socket.close();
}
```

Comment: "every X second" is more like "every second" (not real problem, just noting); "send UDP message" is implemented as "send UDP message **and wait for resply**" - is there any reply being sent?

Comment: also bit strange opening the socket for receiving on an unspecified port

Comment: Yes every second or X seconds, but you got the idea ! Yes I'm so stupid, I didn't see that I was waiting for an answer, I took the code just to try but I just begin to understand it now. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: `InterruptedException` should normally *break* out of the loop, that is, **interrupt** the process, just continuing is kind of rude